# How to change android user accounts using Appium?

Tags: android, appium, account, switching

How can we switch between different user accounts added on a android device using Appium?
I need to automate tests for an application for different users on same device.
Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found way to do it using adb shell commands